# Return form result from external PHP

Tags: forms, numbers, action

I have a post type form with action to an external PHP that calculates a shipping tax.

```
<form id="shipping_costs" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="tarif.php" target="blank">
<input type="hidden" name="serviciu" value="Standard">
```

All the inputs are hidden and the website that receives all the values calculates the tax.

How can I retrieve the resulted amount into my website?

Also, the website I work on is using smarty.

Comment: please post some code from your form/site.

Comment: Add some code... `<?php echo $_POST["name_of_post"]; ?>`

Comment: Search in net before asking your question. use ajax call or <?php echo $_POST["value"]; ?> or echo htmlentities($_POST['contact_list']);